# SQL - Work out frequency (monthly, quarterly and annually) between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, I have two date columns column x and y and I would like to work out the frequency between these two dates if it's monthly, quarterly or annually.

I have tried myself but it seems to be incorrect

Code:

```
CASE WHEN ROUND(DATEDIFF(d, ISNULL(RV.[x], ''), ISNULL(RV.[y], ''))/30.0, 1) <= 1 THEN 'MONTHLY'    
     WHEN ROUND(DATEDIFF(d, ISNULL(RV.[x], ''), ISNULL(RV.[y], ''))/30.0, 1) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'QUARTERLY'   
     ELSE 'ANNUALLY'  
END  FREQUENCY
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help me code this correctly.

Thank you and much appreciated

Comment: It depends on your definitions and how you account especial cases. Example You can say any diff >= 30 days is monthly and any diff >= 365 days id annually but this can fail for first and last days of  a 31 days month and for a leap year. You can extend the rule to add and those months/years in that dates are not the same. It's not a SQL question is a requisites one

Comment: If you can be certain that the `Day` is going to be the same for any given frequency, then the solution is reduced to checking the difference between the `Month` (and `Year`) portions of the dates. 

In fact... even if the day moves around +/- 3 days (or so), you can do the calculations and ignore the days.

That is... the frequency between '2017-01-13' and '2017-04-13' is `4 - 1 = 3` (quarterly).

Answer (score 0):

If you would run it on mock data with some NULL values for the dates then you would notice that the DATEDIFF sometimes returns negative values.
Which would make that CASE return "MONTHLY" for the wrong reason.

Just don't do the ISNULL's. That way the DATEDIFF will just return NULL for those and be evaluated to "ANNUALLY".

Also, you can also get the DATEDIFF in f.e. months, which could simplify your query.

```
declare @TestTable table (x date, y date);

declare @y date = '2017-08-15'; 

insert into @TestTable (x,y) values
(dateadd(day,-10,@y),@y),
(dateadd(day,-30,@y),@y),
(dateadd(day,-60,@y),@y),
(dateadd(day,-240,@y),@y),
(null,@y),
(dateadd(month,-2,@y),null);

select RV.*,
/* 
DATEDIFF(day, RV.[x], RV.[y]) as monthdiff,
DATEDIFF(month, RV.[x], RV.[y]) as monthdiff,
DATEDIFF(quarter, RV.[x], RV.[y]) as quarterdiff,
DATEDIFF(year, RV.[x], RV.[y]) as yeardiff,
*/
CASE 
 WHEN DATEDIFF(month, RV.[x], RV.[y]) = 0 THEN 'MONTHLY'  
 WHEN DATEDIFF(quarter, RV.[x], RV.[y]) = 0 THEN 'QUARTERLY'
 WHEN DATEDIFF(year, RV.[x], RV.[y]) = 0 THEN 'ANNUALLY'
 ELSE 'ANNUALLY?'
END FREQUENCY
from @TestTable RV;
```

Returns:

```
x           y           FREQUENCY
----------  ----------  ----------
2017-08-05  2017-08-15  MONTHLY
2017-07-16  2017-08-15  QUARTERLY
2017-06-16  2017-08-15  ANNUALLY
2016-12-18  2017-08-15  ANNUALLY?
NULL        2017-08-15  ANNUALLY?
2017-06-15  NULL        ANNUALLY?
```

Check also the result of this test SQL:

```
select RV.*, 
DATEDIFF(day, x, y) as daydiff,
DATEDIFF(month, x, y) as monthdiff,
DATEDIFF(quarter, x, y) as quarterdiff,
case when DATEDIFF(quarter, RV.[x], RV.[y]) = 0 then 'yes' else 'no' end as same_quarter
from (values 
('2017-01-15','2017-03-31'),
('2017-01-15','2017-04-01')
) as RV(x,y);
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the prompt answers. Interesting answers. Much appreciated

Comment: @SatyenGotecha Sorry, made a logical mistake. See updated version.

Comment: @LukStorms Logically, the comparison statements make no sense. But, I do realise that is a carry-over from the OP.

Common sense tells me that the following is more correct: `... DATEDIFF(month, RV.[x], RV.[y]) = 1 THEN 'MONTHLY'  WHEN DATEDIFF(month, RV.[x], RV.[y]) = 3 THEN 'QUARTERLY' ... `, and then if the `year` difference is one, then `YEARLY`.

Comment: @PeterAbolins Indeed, I merely tried to correct his issue with result.  And personally I would have that CASE default to something else than 'ANNUALLY'.

Comment: @PeterAbolins Would `DATEDIFF(quarter, RV.[x], RV.[y]) = 0` be usefull ?

Comment: @LukStorms Indeed, it would. The OP then needs to decide what to do with all the cases which fall outside his Monthly, Quarterly and Annually frequencies. Maybe a default frequency of unknown? ie: `ELSE 'UNKNOWN'`

Comment: @SatyenGotecha You hadn't added the expected results, so then  I assume we nailed it anyway.:) Don't forget to check the last test query.  That was added  to make it visually clear what's to expect from a monthly/quarterly datadiff.